# Create RDS DB Security Group using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-rds

I want to create a db security group before creating an RDS instance using Ansible. There is a module for called ec2_group which creates security groups for VPC but I want to create security group for the DB instance only.

Is there a separate module for it or do I have to use the ec2_group module to create a DB security group?

Also, if I'm wrong correct me! The EC2 security group and DB security group are 2 different things right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no Ansible module for that.
DB SG and VPC SG are indeed different things: you create DB SG and allow traffic flow from one of VPC SGs.

If you need to automate DB SG creation, your option is `aws cli`.
Use local commands `aws rds create-db-security-group` and `aws rds authorize-db-security-group-ingress` with Ansible `command` module.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/21336) last year to add 2 AWS modules : `boto3` and `boto3_wait`.

These 2 modules allow you to interact with AWS API using boto3.

For instance, you could create a DB security group by calling [`create_db_security_group`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.create_db_security_group) and [`authorize_db_security_group_ingress`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.authorize_db_security_group_ingress) methods on RDS service :

```yaml
- name: Create DB security group
  boto3:
    name: rds
    region: us-east-1
    operation: create_db_security_group
    parameters:
      DBSecurityGroupName: mydbsecuritygroup
      DBSecurityGroupDescription: My DB security group

- name: Authorize IP range
  boto3:
    name: rds
    region: us-east-1
    operation: authorize_db_security_group_ingress
    parameters:
      DBSecurityGroupName: mydbsecuritygroup
      CIDRIP: 203.0.113.5/32
```

If you're interrested by this feature, feel free to vote up on the PR. :)